# Replace $ with some other character for math

Tags: math-mode, currency

I have little use for math in my latex documents and plenty for typing the dollar sign `$`.  Can I replace the math symbol `$`  with another symbol like `¿`, so that i can use `$` in my text?

Answer (score 5):

you can use `` \catcode`$=12 `` to make `$` a normal character, you don't actually need anything else as you can use `\(` and `\[` to start math, but if you want a character (say `!` then `` \catcode`!=3 `` will make it  a math shift, but it needs to be a single token in the encoding you are using, note that for example ¿ is two bytes in UTF-8 so two tokens if you use pdflatex with UTF-8 encoding)

Comment: In fact, e.g.,  ``\catcode`\•=3`` for example *will* work with the Unicode TeX engines (so XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX but **not** pdfLaTeX). I've used this to make unicode characters active to allow formatting commands to be inserted in verbatim mode, for example.

Comment: One must be careful, however in that some single glyphs such as  are not actually a single character (most flags are two unicode characters although some are more) and depending on the input source you might have é as a single character or as e + ´.

Comment: @DonHosek yes sure in unicode texs there are a lot more single token characters:-)

Comment: I think your language is a bit wrong. A UTF-8 byte sequence is a sequence of 8-bit values (up to four per character), so, for example. • is represented by the UTF-byte sequence `e280a2` (U+2022) and  is represented by `f09f87a8f09f87a6` (U+1F1E8 U+1F1E6). I'm spending a lot of time in Unicode land of late.

Comment: @DonHosek yes I had pdftex in mind, I'll reword

Comment: @DonHosek restricted to the OPs example ¿